# How to make a screensaver work on multiple monitors?

Tags: screensaver

How do I make a screensaver work on multiple monitors?

Windows XP

Comment: Which operating system, which screen saver? Some OSes don't support multi-monitor screen savers, and some individual screen savers don't support multi-monitor display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need a multi monitor screensaver.

I recommend you look at [Really Slick Screensavers](http://www.reallyslick.com/)

Also, as a bonus, they are all free and open source!

Example -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Lifehacker article:

**[Screensavers For Multiple Monitors](http://lifehacker.com/5048568/screensavers-for-multiple-monitors)**

My favorite screensaver: **[Dream Aquarium](http://www.dreamaquarium.com/)**

[image]

> Features:
>
> The most realistic fish motion and
>   behavior of any virtual aquarium.
>
> A fiddler crab that cleans the bottom
>   of the aquarium and chases fish.
>
> Fish have articulated fins, moving
>   eyes, gills and mouth.
>
> Beautiful shifting light rays, ground
>   ripples, gently waving plants that
>   fish can swim into, soft shadows cast
>   by fish, configurable bubble streams,
>   auto-feeding.
>
> dd well over a hundred fish (from 18
>   species), and change settings without
>   having to exit the aquarium.
>
> Widescreen formatting, **multi-monitor
>   support** & much more!

... but it isn't free.

Comment: yeah, they're quite cool, but the fishtank is absolutely spectacular :)

Comment: Deleting first comment because of edit - There are a few things I would pay for, but a screensaver wouldn't be one of them (apart from toast YEARS ago!). I never want my screensaver to show - I want to work, or have the screen off - I just couldn't really imagine paying for one. Anyway - have to say, it does look good!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).  It allows you to put different 'non-multi-monitor-aware' screen savers on different monitors.

> UltraMon is a utility for multi-monitor systems, designed to increase productivity and unlock the full potential of multiple monitors.
>
> - efficiently move windows and maximize windows across the desktop
> - manage more applications with the Smart Taskbar
> - control application positioning with UltraMon Shortcuts
> - **multi-monitor support for desktop wallpapers and *screen savers***
> - mirror your main monitor to secondary monitors for a presentation